# About the Set of $\mathbb{S}=\{ n | n = a^2+b^2, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}. \}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

> About the Set of $\mathbb{S}=\{ n | n = a^2+b^2, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}. \}$

This is also known as [OEIS A001481.](https://oeis.org/A001481)

I just found an interesting one from this set.

From my favorite identity, Brahmagupta-Fibonacci's identity, we can get:

$(ab+cd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2).$

So, we get...

> If $a, b \in \mathbb{S}, ab \in \mathbb{S}.$

This is a well-known fact for the set.

Now, I'm curious about the prime number of the set $\mathbb{S}$.

For example, $2, 5, 9, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 49, 53, 61, 73, 89, 97, 101, 109, 113, 121,  \cdots$ are the prime number of $\mathbb{S}$.

These are all the prime numbers except for $9, 49, 121, \cdots$.

And amazing thing is that they are all square numbers.

So, I'm wondering if the prime numbers of $\mathbb{S}$ except the prime numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ have some pattern.

I can see that they are $(4k+3)^2$... Is it right?

[Extension for this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4540173/979028)

Comment: Euler [himself](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/translations/E228en.pdf) wrote about it.

Comment: The link you provided has a characterization of the numbers in the sequence in term of its prime factorization, so that should answer your question

Comment: "For example, $2, 5, 9, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 49, 53, 61, 73, 89, 97, 101, 109, 113, 121,  \cdots$ are the prime number of $\mathbb{S}$." What exactly did you mean by this? Because $9$ is not a prime number (as you not later).

Comment: @jjagmath The prime number of $\mathbb{S}$ can be defined:
$$ \text{For } p \in \mathbb{S}, \text{ if } \not\exists a \in \mathbb{S} \text{ s.t. } a|p,  p \text{ is the prime number of } \mathbb{S}.$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ummm... Can you tell me the page about my question...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A well-known theorem often attributed to Fermat shows that a prime $p \in \mathbb{N}$ is a sum of two squares if and only if $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. More generally, a positive integer $n$ is a sum of two squares if and only if, for each prime $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ dividing $n$, the largest number $k$ such that $q^k \mid n$ is even. Stated differently, $n$ is a sum of two squares if and only if each prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$ divides $n$ an even number of times.

This is sometimes called [the sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem).

This shows that the "primes" of the set $\mathbb{S}$ are $2$, typical primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and squares $q^2$ of primes $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. This is very nearly what you suggest at the end of your post.

Comment: Yes, this was what I exactly asked. Thanks for the proof. I think I just have to read the book which was written by Fermat and Euler.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Fermat's theorem which states that a prime number can be expressed as sum of two integer squares iff is of the form $4k+1$

Comment: Or if the prime equals 2.