# $\Bbb{S}: \{ ax^2+by^2 \ | \ x, y \in \Bbb{Z} \}$. Find the condition of $a, b$ which makes $\Bbb{S}$ closed for multiplication.

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\Bbb{S}: \{ ax^2+by^2 \ | \ x, y \in \Bbb{Z} \}.$ for the fixed $a, b \in \Bbb{N}$. Then, find the condition of $a, b$ which makes $\Bbb{S}$ closed for multiplication.

\begin{align}
& \text{if } a=b=1: \text{closed for multiplication. (ref)} \\
& \text{if } a=\alpha^2, b=\beta^2: ax^2+by^2=(\alpha x)^2+(\beta y)^2, az^2+bw^2=(\alpha z)^2+(\beta w)^2. \\
\therefore \; & (ax^2+by^2)(az^2+bw^2)=(\alpha^2xz\pm\beta^2yw)^2+(\alpha\beta xw \mp \alpha\beta yz)^2. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \text{closed for multiplication.}
\end{align}

What else can be a condition to $a, b$?

ref) [About the set of $\Bbb{S}=\{n|n=a^2+b^2, a, b \in \Bbb{Z}.\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4485446/979028)

Edit) comment told me that the second example doesn't work... Sorry for my mistake.

Comment says:

$a=1: \\ \Bbb{S}: \{ x^2+by^2 | x, y \in \Bbb{Z} \}. (x^2+by^2)(z^2+bw^2)=(xz\pm byw)^2+b(yz\mp xw)^2. \\ \Rightarrow \text{Closed for multiplication.}$

Comment: This is a question in number theory, not set theory

Comment: @Sam Alright, I'll edit it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Your second example doesn't seem to work.  There is no reason to expect either value of $\alpha^2 xz \pm \beta^2 yw$ to be divisible by $\alpha$ or by $\beta$.

Comment: @RDK Does your $\mathbb N$ include $0$?  If not, then even $a=b=1$ fails because $4 = 2\cdot 2$ is not the sum of non-zero squares.  You could just switch $x,y\in \mathbb Z$ to clarify the intent.

Comment: @ErickWong Oh, I missed it. Thanks! I'll edit it.

Comment: @ErickWong Oh, I meant 'including' $0$... It seems that $\Bbb{Z}$ seems greater.

Comment: For $a=1$ any $b$ works (Brahmagupta identity).  For $a=2$, I think only $b=1,2,4$ work and nothing else.  So the pattern does seem to have some interesting behavior.  I think there are infinitely many $b$s for a given $a$ iff $a$ is a square, but I'm not sure about the finer details.

Comment: @ErickWong Oh... Thanks for the comment. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a (surprisingly recent) [reference](https://opensiuc.lib.siu.edu/math_articles/20/) that answers this question:

> Earnest, A.G. and Fitzgerald, Robert W. "Represented Value Sets for Integral Binary Quadratic Forms and Lattices." (2007).  *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*, 135, 3765–3770.

Corollary 2.5 in particular gives the following necessary and sufficient condition: define $d = \gcd(a,b)$ and let $A = a/d, B = b/d$.  Then $\{ax^2 + by^2\}$ is closed under multiplication iff $d = Ax^2 + By^2$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb Z$.

I said above that the set of $b$ for a given $a$ is infinite iff $a$ is not a square.  This can be seen independently of the above criterion, as I describe below:

It is easy to see by Brahmagupta identity that $k^2 ( x^2 + ny^2 )$ also satisfies the multiplicative property, so if $a=k^2$ then we can take any $b = nk^2$.  On the other hand, if $a$ is not a square, then $a \in \mathcal S$, so in order for $\mathcal S$ to be closed we need $a^2 \in \mathcal S$, hence $a^2 = ax^2 + by^2$ for some $x,y$.  Since $a$ is not a square, we cannot have $y=0$, so then $y^2 \ge 1$ and $b \le a^2$, so there are only finitely many values of $b$.

Comment: Nice answer! That's why all $x^2+by^2$ always worked...